# Does Azure Synapse Link to Cosmos DB work with Managed Identity?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-synapse

Does Azure Synapse Link to Cosmos DB work with Managed Identity?

I created an identity using the code below

```
CREATE CREDENTIAL [xavcosmosdb]
WITH IDENTITY = 'Managed Identity'
GO
```

When I use it as

```
SELECT TOP 100 *
FROM OPENROWSET(​PROVIDER = 'CosmosDB',
                CONNECTION = 'Account=xavcosmosdb;Database=myDb',
                OBJECT = 'cases',
                SERVER_CREDENTIAL = 'xavcosmosdb'
) AS [cases]
```

I get the following error.

```
Resolving CosmosDB path has failed with error 'Secret is null or empty.'.
```

What are the steps to use managed identity from Azure Synapse to CosmosDb?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not supported. No ETA for now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).